# Invalid Byte Sequence In UTF-8 Ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, ruby-2.0

I have the string like this `"abce\xC3".sub("a","A")`, when i execute the line i get the following error.

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
    from (irb):20:in `sub'
    from (irb):20
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The byte "\xC3" is not a valid UTF-8 character. Your problem occurs in some way when you obtain this value from source (or your assumptions about how Ruby strings can be manipulated). To get help, you will need to explain a little about what this value is supposed to represent, or how it has been read into your program.

Comment: Where does the `\xC3` come from? In UTF-8 it means a second byte (like `\xA4` for `ä`) must follow.

Comment: "ITZVÃ" this is the exact string. I am working on.

Comment: Seems like Ruby 2.2 doesn't raise an error, i.e. `sub` works with / skips invalid byte sequences.

Comment: "ITZVÃ" is content of file. When i read the file. `z = File.open("x"); z.read(5);` Then output should be `ITZV\xC3\x83` instead i am getting `ITZV\xC3`. @Stefan any idea about why this is happening in ruby.

Comment: @Vijay see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31286335/477037) below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Arie already answered this error is because invalid byte sequence `\xC3`

If you are using Ruby 2.1 +, you can also use [`String#scrub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scrub) to replace invalid bytes with given replacement character. Here:

```
a = "abce\xC3"
# => "abce\xC3" 
a.scrub
# => "abce�"
a.scrub.sub("a","A")
# => "Abce�"
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to figure out what do you want the `\xC3` to be. Does it represents the char `Ã`?

You see the error because `\xC3` isn't valid byte sequence in the (default) UTF-8 encoding. You can first correct the encoding of the String (by answering the question above), and then do the replacement.

```
"abce\xC3".force_encoding("iso-8859-1").sub('a', 'A')
```

Or if the encoding doesn't matter, say, you're processing byte sequence rather than character sequence, you can force the encoding to `ASCII-8BIT`.

```
"abce\xC3".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").sub('a', 'A')
```

Comment: how you found \xC3 is Ã ?

Comment: And to convert the string to UTF-8 use `"abce\xC3".force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')` or - better yet - set the correct encoding when reading the string.

Comment: @Vijay It's a single byte which exceeds the range of normal ASCII encoding, so I tried the [8 bit encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#8-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272763/invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-ruby#comment50547921_31272763) / actual problem:

> `"ITZVÃ"` is content of file. When i read the file.
>
> ```
>  z = File.open("x")
>  z.read(5)
> ```
>
> Then output should be `ITZV\xC3\x83` instead i am getting `ITZV\xC3`

This is because in UTF-8, `Ã` is a multibyte character, i.e. your string has 5 *characters*, but 6 *bytes*:

```
"ITZVÃ".chars #=> ["I", "T", "Z", "V", "Ã"]
"ITZVÃ".bytes #=> [ 73,  84,  90,  86, 195, 131]
```

`z.read(5)` reads 5 *bytes* from your files, thus returning an incomplete UTF-8 string:

```
require 'tempfile'

z = Tempfile.new('foo')
z << 'ITZVÃ'

z.rewind
z.read(5) #=> "ITZV\xC3"
```

You have to read 6 bytes instead:

```
z.rewind
z.read(6) #=> "ITZV\xC3\x83"
```

Note that [`read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-read) always returns ASCII-8BIT encoded strings. You have to set a different encoding manually:

```
z.rewind
z.read(6).force_encoding('utf-8') #=> "ITZVÃ"
```